# append ajax result to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm making an ajax call to the IMDb API to get the movie data for 'The Shawshank Redemption'. I want this data to be put in the div I created.

```
<div id="movie-data"></div>
```

My js code currently:

```
$(init);


function init() {

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0111161",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#movie-data").append(data);
        }
    });
```

It doesn't give any response. However, I can see the data in my console. When I append `<p>Test</p>` instead of `data` it does return 'Test' to the screen.

Comment: what is value of `data`?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar `data` is all information about the movie

Comment: can you share that value.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I don't know any more than you know. If you visit the url you can find all the info about the movie. [link](http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0111161)

Answer (score 5):

This is what I did. It seems to be working now. Thanks everyone.

```
 $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0111161",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#movie-data").append(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work

```
$("#movie-data").html(data.Title);
```

because `data` will be in json format, like this:

```
{"Title":"Titanic","Year":"1997","Rated":"PG-13","Released":"19 Dec 1997","Runtime":"3 h 14 min","Genre":"Drama, Romance","Director":"James Cameron","Writer":"James Cameron","Actors":"Leonardo DiCaprio, Kate Winslet, Billy Zane, Kathy Bates","Plot":"A seventeen-year-old aristocrat, expecting to be married to a rich claimant by her mother, falls in love with a kind but poor artist aboard the luxurious, ill-fated R.M.S. Titanic.","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjExNzM0NDM0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzkxOTUwNw@@._V1_SX300.jpg","imdbRating":"7.6","imdbVotes":"449,162","imdbID":"tt0120338","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}
```

Check these resources:

[Using AJAX to Extract Data from IMDB API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474410/using-ajax-to-extract-data-from-imdb-api)

http://99webtools.com/blog/php-get-movie-information-from-imdb/

Comment: if its failing for append, it will fail for html as well

Comment: I tried the second option and now it's returning [object Object].

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. API is returning `JSON` values you need to get the values like mentioned below. Hope this helps you.

```
var content = 'Title : '+data.Title ;
content += ' Year : '+data.Year ;
content += ' Rated : '+data.Rated ;
content += ' Released : '+data.Released ;
$("#movie-data").append(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="movie-data"></div>
function init() {
var html='';
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0111161",
        success: function (data) {
            for(var key in data) {
            var value = data[key];
                html+='<div>'+key+':'+value+'</div>'
            }
            $("#movie-data").append(html);

        }
    });
}
init();
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dbnh1g29/)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is:

```
function init() {

$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0111161",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#movie-data").html($(data).append(data));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to delete dataType: "json" from your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0111161",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#movie-data").append(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: Seems that OP tried it (based on [their own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29433601/7404943))

Answer (score 0):

The code would be the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
    method:"get",
    url:'{{ route('getnotificationcount') }}',
    success:function(data){
            console.log(data); 

        for(var key in data) {
        var value = data[key];
        html+='<div>'+key+':'+value+'</div>'
        }
        $("#notifyy").append(html);
        
    

    }
});

});
```