# Refresh a DIV on ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page with has a heading say :

```
<div class="something"><? some php code  ?></div>
```

In that page I also have an ajax doing a job like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $("#loader").show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $("#loader").hide();
});
});

$('#link').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault;
 var href = this.getAttribute('href');  
 $.ajax({
url: href,
success: function(text) {
  alert("Added Succesfully");
}
});
return false; 
});
</script>
```

Now in the success in ajax i also want to refresh the div i mentioned. Only refresh as it is attached to PHP which will fetch data from an external API. Is this possible ?

Comment: `$('.something').html('Your text or code here');` <- inside success callback

Comment: I don't think we can refresh the div, instead we can keep the content in another php file and set the new values

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh the div"? If you want to append result from ajax call you can use `$('.something').append(data-from-ajax)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432997/append-ajax-result-to-div)

```
 $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0111161",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#movie-data").append(JSON.stringify(data));
```

With the `append` function you can *insert* the data from the ajax call into a div. [explanation and example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp)

> The append() method inserts specified content at the end of the selected elements.
>
> **Tip:** To insert content at the beginning of the selected elements, use the prepend() method.

Or maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490026/refresh-reload-the-content-in-div-using-jquery-ajax) answer can fix your issue

or you can take a look at the [jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.
> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data.

Comment: I didn't use the code but I got your point. It worked perfectly, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You could put your php code in an external file and reload your div by calling `JQuery` load method:

```
$("#something").load("mycode.php");
```

**I hope it helps you.**